# unexpected behavior of directory renaming in macos (other posix flavors?)

Tags: macos, shell, filesystems, posix, apfs

Basically, in Python or bash I can rename a directory to a different name from within that directory :  at that point, from within the directory, the old name still shows, but the rename has in fact already taken place.

On macos with APFS, this came about in a Python script I was writing to rename directories as per a specific naming convention I use and I noticed this behavior.

I am posting this as posix/shell/macos as I half expect this to happen as well under Linux and I got the same general behavior out of the zshell.

Let's say I have a directory, `foo`:

```
(venv) jluc@test$ tree
.
└── foo
```

I rename it to bar with `mv foo bar`

```
(venv) jluc@test$ tree
.
└── bar
```

But now, let's cd into that directory and perform the rename there.

```
$cd bar
$pwd
/Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/test/bar
$ mv ../bar ../zoom
$ pwd
/Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/test/bar   still the old name
```

So, now, within `bar`, I've renamed it to `zoom`.  It did not error out.  Locally, a `pwd` shows that I am still in the same directory.  I can do an `ls` and I am not in a invalid directory which some commands can sometime put me in.

However, a tree one level up tells a different story.

```
(venv) jluc@bar$ tree ..
..
└── zoom   but here I see the new name
```

and cd to the current directory fails

```
cd `pwd`
-bash: cd: /Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/test/bar: No such file or directory
```

What, in the name of Schrodinger's , is going on?  Does the inode scheme underlying the file system, APFS, provide this?  Would different filesystems, like ext4 for example also exhibit the same behavior?

Update:  if I have a separate text file in my testing directory, I can `cat` the contents of the file before and after the rename locally, so it's not just the shell - the file system collaborates as well.  The current directory is still valid and operational (which would fit with @that other guy's answer).

Comment: This isn't a filesystem thing, it's just bash (and hence `pwd`) being a little out-of-date about where you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at play:

1. On Unix, any handle to an open file or directory will generally be unaffected by renames and deletions.
2. The shell remembers the directory you're in, it doesn't re-query every time.

#1 means that for the most part, you can delete or move a file/dir that's still in use, and the using process can continue using it until it's done.  #2 means that the shell's `pwd` will just return the old name (though external `/bin/pwd` which has to requery will fail).

Comment: So, wrt #1, would you consider this to be a kernel-level behavior?  I can also `cat` the contents of a file in my renamed directory, so it goes beyond just *an open file*.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely kernel level behavior. Due to this behavior, `.` will still reference the same inode after a move, so you can still `cat` files relative to it.